# Spring JPA - How to remove object from database but not in relation

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Hello I'm using spring boot and JPA relations.

I have two entities, *Product* and *User*, I want to create relationship between them, and save all bought products.

But if I delete product from entity then it will be deleted from new table (relationship), how to remedy it?

Maybe collect old records from table ?

Comment: You want to retain it in the child table even if its deleted from parent table. Then it will be an orphaned child in the relationship and that product id will point to nothing

Comment: So how I could keep all user shopping history ?

Comment: You can't delete the product entity in that case. you just need to deactivate it or arhive it.

Comment: So what is better, not delete product, whether create new entity, whose will keep information from transactions

Comment: What you are going to achieve will defeat the purpose of table relationship and hence data integrity (RDBMS basis concepts). Why you need to have a relationship among tables then if you want to keep orphan entries? I guess removing the relationship will solve your purpose.

Comment: I just wanted to know how to do that, I was considering other way to solve it..
But its true, it make no sense at the moment, so removing the relationship will be good idea.
Thanks

Comment: Instead of "how to remedy it?", can you update your question to indicate what your expected behavior is exactly so posters know what solution you're aiming at?

Answer (score 0):

in jpa when delete product by jpa must delete this product from user

you can delete from ProductRepository   by `deleteById(Long productId)`